# Create lambda from docker image with azure devops package

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a custom library that is a query to do some internal queries in a lamba, at this moment the zip with the query is called build-sales-pivot-sql, I packaged this zip and uploaded azure artifacts through twine..

Then I tried to install it on my windows machine and it installed correctly...

```
C:\Users\rocker>pip install build-sales-pivot-sql
Looking in indexes: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/myproject/_packaging/queries_lambdas/pypi/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: build-sales-pivot-sql in c:\users\leo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (0.1)
```

Now what I'm trying to do is install that azure devops package in a lambda that is created from a docker image, having the corresponding files.

`Dockerfile`

```
COPY lambda.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install our dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "lambda.lambda_handler" ]
```

`pip.conf`

```
extra-index-url=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/myproject/_packaging/queries_lambdas/pypi/simple/
trusted-host = pkgs.dev.azure.com
username = myuser@mydomain.com
password = tokenxxxxxxxxx
[install]
trusted-host = pkgs.dev.azure.com
```

```
requirements.txt
```

```
awswrangler
build-sales-pivot-sql
```

```
lambda.py... my lambda code in python
```

```
commands:
```

```
docker build -t sales .
```

result:

```
[+] Building 24.9s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                             0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 252B                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                   21.6s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 110B                                                                                                0.0s 
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:af38b5d60e73a971088774fd9de87621f5425a55813970ea74357bb2de1ed246              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY lambda.py                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [3/4] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"                                               3.1s 
------
 > [4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}":
#8 2.359 Collecting awswrangler
#8 2.619   Downloading awswrangler-2.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (272 kB)
#8 2.682      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 272.3/272.3 KB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#8 2.825 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement build-sales-pivot-sql (from versions: none)
#8 2.825 ERROR: No matching distribution found for build-sales-pivot-sql
#8 3.010 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
#8 3.010 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"]: exit code: 1
```

I already tried to put build-sales-pivot-sql==0.1 in the requirements file and I get the same error.

Comment: I found the solution is the following: in the pip.conf it should go like this `[global]
extra-index-url=https://mytoken@pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorganization/myproject/_packaging/queries_lambdas/pypi/simple/`
and ready with that the image will get the artifacts package